# Advice needed about deploying website backend files to webserver from git repo

Tags: permissions, git, webserver, gitlab

We are trying to improve the management of our website backend files, and are planning to deploy (using `git pull`) the files from the git repo (hosted on a local (within our organisation) GitLab server) to a test web server, and then in turn from the repo to the live web server (which will be new and starting from scratch, as the current server is approaching end of OS support).

We are a very small team and don't have much in the way of resources (time, mainly), but it is likely that at least 2 people will be updating different parts of the website.

I am trying to foresee potential issues with this plan and work out how to resolve them.

First of all, file ownership. Our previous setup had each of us doing everything as root and we want to avoid this as much as possible. We have created a new unix group for the website files and have added the devops team (and the apache user) to it, with the intention of using `setgid` to ensure that files can be created and then updated without file permission problems. (What would be even better would be if there were some way that the devops team could write to the files, but that Apache could only read them?)

Regarding git itself, I am assuming that having different people using git pull is likely to be problematic, with the files in the `.git` folder possibly owned by and only accessible to the person whose actions last updated them (unless it is possible to successfully apply `setgid` to this folder as well?).

Is this plan likely to be workable, or are there yet more potential problems that we have not foreseen? Are there other (preferably not very complicated, given our limited resources) ways that we could attempt to do something similar?

Comment: You seem to have locked yourself into your "improvement" method before really designing the method, and learning the tools. Back Up -

Comment: No, only trying to think through a possible solution, and seeking advice as to whether it is workable, or whether there are other ways of achieving the same goal that we are unaware of.